# Python game code - attack damage of new item not replacing old item attack damage

Tags: python

For some reason the attack damage doesn't update or get replaced when the user buys a upgraded weapon.

```
import random
import time

level = 10
enemies = []
player = []
area = 0
#Need to set toeliath boss as global variable
toeliath_boss = {
        "Name": "Toeliath",
        "Weapon": "Fangs",
        "level": random.randint(20, 30),
        "Health": random.randint(60, 80),
        "Attack": ["Bite of Agony", random.randrange(20, 35), "Venomous Grasp", random.randrange(25, 45)],
        "is_defeatable": False
    }


#Setting defult value as false for bossbalt if not passed as an argument to the function
def battlesystem(enemy_type=None, boss_battle=False):
    global level, enemies, player, area
    global enemy
    global enemyHealth
    global enemyAttack
    global toeliath_boss
#List of enemys
    enemies = [{"Name": "Goblin", "Weapon": "Sword", "level": random.randint(1, 10),
                "Health": random.randint(12, 20),
                "Attack": ["Sword swipe", random.randrange(4, 9), "Gut puncture", random.randrange(8, 15)]},
               {"Name": "Barbarian", "Weapon": "Fist", "level": random.randint(3, 15),
                "Health": random.randint(20, 25),
                "Attack": ["Primal swipe", random.randrange(8, 12), "Brutish elbow", random.randrange(9, 14)]},
               {"Name": "Skeleton", "Weapon": "Gun", "level": random.randint(5, 16),
                "Health": random.randint(12, 19),
                "Attack": ["Blazing bullets", random.randrange(10, 18), "Pistol Whip", random.randrange(6, 12)]}]
    # Boss enemy
    toeliath_boss = {
        "Name": "Toeliath",
        "Weapon": "Fangs",
        "level": random.randint(20, 30),
        "Health": random.randint(60, 80),
        "Attack": ["Bite of Agony", random.randrange(20, 35), "Venomous Grasp", random.randrange(25, 45)],
        "is_defeatable": False
    }

    if boss_battle:
        enemy = toeliath_boss
    else:
        H = random.randint(0, 2)
        enemy = enemies[H]

    enemyHealth = enemy["Health"]
    enemyAttack = enemy["Attack"]

    player = ["You", "Human", level, 30,
          ["Pheonix punches", random.randint(5, 11), "poisonous intimidation", random.randint(4, 9)]]


    playerCharacter = {"Name": player[0], "Type": player[1], "Level": player[2], "Health": player[3], "Attack": player[4]}
    playerCharacterHealth = playerCharacter["Health"]

    print("An enemy", enemy["Name"], "has challenged you!")
    print("It's level", enemy["level"])
    print("It has", enemy["Health"], "health")

    while True:
        print("Press f to fight or r to run away")

        playerChoice = input().lower()

        if playerChoice == "f":
            print("You have chosen to fight against,", enemy["Name"])
            break
        elif playerChoice == "r":
            print("You ran away back to the Jail Cell")
            jailCell2()
            break
        else:
            print("Error")

    print(playerCharacter["Name"], "have", playerCharacterHealth, "health")
#Enemy attack randomiser, will generate a random choice of enemy which will have a random level and amount of health
    while enemyHealth > 0 and playerCharacterHealth > 0:

        while True:
            print("Press 1 for", playerCharacter["Name"], "to attack with",
                  playerCharacter["Attack"][0], "or 2 to attack with",
                  playerCharacter["Attack"][2])

            attackChoice = int(input())

            if attackChoice == 1:
                if len(player) > 4:  # Check if player has a new attack
                    playerAttack = player[4][1]
                else:
                    playerAttack = playerCharacter["Attack"][1]
                
                print(playerCharacter["Name"], "attack with", playerCharacter["Attack"][0],
                    "for", playerAttack, "damage")
                enemyHealth -= playerAttack
                print("enemy health", enemyHealth)
            elif attackChoice == 2:
                if len(player) > 5:  # Check if player has a new attack
                    playerAttack = player[5][1]
                else:
                    playerAttack = playerCharacter["Attack"][3]
                print(playerCharacter["Name"], "attack with", playerCharacter["Attack"][2],
                    "for", playerAttack, "damage")
                enemyHealth -= playerAttack
                print("enemy health", enemyHealth)
            else:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter 1 or 2.")
                continue

            if enemyHealth <= 0 or playerCharacterHealth <= 0:
                break

            enemyBattleRandomiser = random.choice([0, 2])
            print(enemy["Name"], "attacks you with", enemy["Attack"][enemyBattleRandomiser],
                  "for", enemy["Attack"][enemyBattleRandomiser+1], "damage")
            playerCharacterHealth -= enemy["Attack"][enemyBattleRandomiser+1]
            print(playerCharacter["Name"], "have", playerCharacterHealth, "health")

            if playerCharacterHealth <= 0:
                break

    if playerCharacterHealth > 0:
        print("YOU WIN!")
        if area == 1:
            jailCell()
        elif area == 2:
            darkPassage()
        elif area ==3:
            tortureRoom()
        elif area ==4:
            wineCeller()
        elif area ==5:
            print("You defeated the infamous Toeliath! YOU'VE WON THE GAME!!")
            play_again()
    else:
        print("Game Over!")
        play_again()
        
# Function to restart game if user looses
def play_again():
    while True:
        choice = input("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ").lower()
        if choice == "y":
            main_menu()
            break
        elif choice == "n":
            exit(2)
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please enter Y or N.")
            

def jailCell():
    global area
    global money
    global player
    area = 1
    print("Jail Cell:")
    print("")
    print("You wake up in a jail cell, it's cold, dark, and very eerie. You better watch out for enemies!")
    print("")
    print("""You walk out of your cell and to your left you see a sign, the sign says Store & Casino.
        But to your right you see a dark passage.""")
    print("")
    print("""You've got an option: type L to walk left and go to the Store & Casino or type R to go right, into a strange passage.""")

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "L":
            money,player = store_and_flip_coin(money,player)  # Pass money as an argument
            break
        elif user_input == "R":
            darkPassage()
            break
        else:
            print("Input Error")

#2nd jaiCell function so when player wants to run from enemy he can get put back to his jailcell without introduction playing
def jailCell2():
    global area
    global money
    global player
    area = 1
    print("Jail Cell:")
    print("")
    print("""You've got an option: type L to walk left and go to the Store & Casino or type R to go right, into a strange passage.""")

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "L":
            money,player = store_and_flip_coin(money,player)  # Pass money as an argument
            break
        elif user_input == "R":
            darkPassage()
            break
        else:
            print("Input Error, please type L or R")

def darkPassage():
    global area
    area = 2
    print("The dark passage!")
    print("")
    print("You slowly creep down the hallway, searching for any potential enemies, you better watch out!")
    print("")
    print("Press S to go south, back to your jail cell")
    print("Or press N to to onwards...")
    battleChance = random.randint(1, 3)
    if battleChance == 1:
        battlesystem()
    else:
        print()

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "S":
            jailCell2()
        elif user_input == "N":
            tortureRoom()
        else:
            print("Input error")


def tortureRoom():
    global area
    area = 3
    print("The Torture Room!")
    print("You've entered a dark and terrifying torture room. Be careful and watch out for traps and enemies.")
    print("Press S to go south, back to the dark passage")
    print("Or press N to continue exploring...")
    battleChance = random.randint(1,3)
    if battleChance ==1:
        battlesystem()
    else:
        print()

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "S":
            darkPassage()
        elif user_input == "N":
            wineCeller()
            
        else:
            print("Input error")
            
def wineCeller():
    global area
    area = 4
    print("The Wine Celler Room!")
    print("You've entered a dank cold wine celler with for some reason all the wine being missing?!.")
    print("You spot a hidden trap door")
    print("Press S to go south, back to the torture room")
    print("Or press T to investigate the trap door...")
    battleChance = random.randint(1,3)
    if battleChance ==1:
        battlesystem()
    else:
        print()

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "S":
            tortureRoom()
        elif user_input == "N":
            print("You continue exploring the torture room...")
        elif user_input == "T":
            trapdoorBoss()
            battlesystem(enemy_type="toeliath")  # Pass "toeliath" as an enemy_type parameter to spawn Toeliath
        else:
            print("Input error")
            
def trapdoorBoss():
    global area
    area = 5
    print("You enter the trap door!")
    print("Torches light up in flames around you like a circle!")
    print("You get an uneasy feeling...")
    print("BOOM!")
    print("THE GIANT BOSS TOELIATH HAS APPEARD")
    print("You have no other choice but to fight!")
    battleChance = random.randint(0, 1)
    if battleChance == 1:
        battlesystem(boss_battle=True)
        toeliath_boss 
        
    else:
        print()


def store_and_flip_coin(money,player):  
    while True:
        print("Welcome to the casino/shop!")
        choice = input("Do you want to gamble (g), shop (s), or go back to the jail cell (b)?: ").lower()
        if choice == "g":
            money = gamble(money)
        elif choice == "s":
            money,player = store(money,player)
        elif choice == "b":
            jailCell()
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")

# starting amount of money
money = 200000

# coinflip script
def flip_coin():
    return random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])

def gamble(money):
    while True:
        print("You have", money, "dollars")
        bet = take_bet(money)
        coin = flip_coin()
        print("The coin landed on", coin, "")
        if coin == 'heads':
            money += bet
            print("You won", bet, "dollars!")
        else:
            money -= bet
            print("You lost", bet, "dollars")
        if money <= 0:
            print("Game over, you ran out of money")
            break
        play_again = input("Play again? (Y/N): ")
        if play_again.lower() == "n":
            break
    return money


def store(money,player,):
    global toeliath_boss  
    
    print("Welcome to the store where you can buy upgraded weapons and armor.")
    store_items = [{"Name": "God Sword",
                    "Attack": 14,
                     "Cost": 75},
                    {"Name": "Mystical wand of light",
                    "Attack": 16,
                     "Cost": 100,},
                     {"Name": "Admin Power",
                      "Attack": 6666,
                     "Cost": 6666},
                      {"Name": "Slingshot",
                       "Attack": 1000, "Cost": 250}]

    # display store items
    print("Available items:")
    for item in store_items:
        item_details = f"{item['Name']} - Cost: {item['Cost']}"
        if 'Attack' in item:
            item_details += f", Attack: {item['Attack']}"
        print(item_details)

    # allow player to buy items
    while True:
        item_name = input("Enter the name of the item you want to buy (or press enter to exit): ")
        if not item_name:
            break
        for item in store_items:
            if item['Name'] == item_name:
                if item['Cost'] > money:
                    print("Not enough money")
                else:
                    money -= item['Cost']
                    print(f"You bought {item_name} for {item['Cost']} dollars")

                    # Update player's attack damage when item is purchased in store
                    if 'Attack' in item:
                        player.append(["New Attack 1", item['Attack']])
                        player.append(["New Attack 2", item['Attack']])

                        
                    if item_name == "Slingshot":
                        toeliath_boss["is_defeatable"] = True

                    break
        else:
            print("Item not found")

    print(f"Money left after store: {money}")
    return money, player


def take_bet(money):
    while True:
        try:
            bet = int(input("Enter your bet: "))
            if bet <= money:
                return bet
            else:
                print("You don't have enough money to make that bet.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
#main menue to give user greeting and instructions on how to play
def main_menu():
    global money
    while True:
        print("Welcome to Dungeons Of Dark!")
        print("This is a simple text-based turn game where you've been locked in a dungeon.")
        print("Follow along with what the game tells you, and you'll be fine.")
        print("Make sure to earn money by betting on a coin flip and use that money to buy yourself upgraded weapons.")
        print("To win make sure you have the Slingshot!")
        print("Good luck and have fun!")
        user_input = input("Press Enter to start the game...")
        if user_input == "":
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please try again..")

    jailCell()

# Call the main_menu function to start the game
main_menu()
```

What can I try next?

Comment: what exactly does not work for you? I ran it, bought some items in shop and I see global variable "player" is updated - contains new elements

Comment: `player` variable is a list with 5 elements at the start, and the last element `player[4]` is attack-related. But when you buy the item, you add 2 elements to the list, so it will have 7 elements. The index should be `player[5][1]` and `player [6][1]` or sth like that. May be an index problem? Also, `playerCharacter[Attack]` still points to `player[4]`.

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) API, but not in general for questions about games written in Python.

Comment: You need to put the player variable outside the battle function. You re-assign the variable player when the battle started, so the newly bought item will disappear. It's like creating a new character every time a battle starts, which makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify some code and now it works as your intended. The point is you should put the player variable outside the function. Also when buying a new item in the shop, to make things simple, just replace the old Attack. I comment on the part the I change in the code

```
import random
import time

level = 10
enemies = []

area = 0
# Need to set toeliath boss as global variable
toeliath_boss = {
    "Name": "Toeliath",
    "Weapon": "Fangs",
    "level": random.randint(20, 30),
    "Health": random.randint(60, 80),
    "Attack": ["Bite of Agony", random.randrange(20, 35), "Venomous Grasp", random.randrange(25, 45)],
    "is_defeatable": False
}
player = ["You", "Human", level, 30,
                 ["Pheonix punches", random.randint(5, 11), "poisonous intimidation", random.randint(4, 9)]]




# Setting defult value as false for bossbalt if not passed as an argument to the function
def battlesystem(enemy_type=None, boss_battle=False):
    # Player related
    playerCharacter = {"Name": player[0], "Type": player[1], "Level": player[2], "Health": player[3],
                       "Attack": player[4]}
    playerCharacterHealth = playerCharacter["Health"]
    print(playerCharacter["Name"], "have", playerCharacterHealth, "health")
    # List of enemys
    enemies = [{"Name": "Goblin", "Weapon": "Sword", "level": random.randint(1, 10),
                "Health": random.randint(12, 20),
                "Attack": ["Sword swipe", random.randrange(4, 9), "Gut puncture", random.randrange(8, 15)]},
               {"Name": "Barbarian", "Weapon": "Fist", "level": random.randint(3, 15),
                "Health": random.randint(20, 25),
                "Attack": ["Primal swipe", random.randrange(8, 12), "Brutish elbow", random.randrange(9, 14)]},
               {"Name": "Skeleton", "Weapon": "Gun", "level": random.randint(5, 16),
                "Health": random.randint(12, 19),
                "Attack": ["Blazing bullets", random.randrange(10, 18), "Pistol Whip", random.randrange(6, 12)]}]
    # Boss enemy
    toeliath_boss = {
        "Name": "Toeliath",
        "Weapon": "Fangs",
        "level": random.randint(20, 30),
        "Health": random.randint(60, 80),
        "Attack": ["Bite of Agony", random.randrange(20, 35), "Venomous Grasp", random.randrange(25, 45)],
        "is_defeatable": False
    }

    if boss_battle:
        enemy = toeliath_boss
    else:
        H = random.randint(0, 2)
        enemy = enemies[H]

    enemyHealth = enemy["Health"]
    enemyAttack = enemy["Attack"]


    print("An enemy", enemy["Name"], "has challenged you!")
    print("It's level", enemy["level"])
    print("It has", enemy["Health"], "health")

    while True:
        print("Press f to fight or r to run away")

        playerChoice = input().lower()

        if playerChoice == "f":
            print("You have chosen to fight against,", enemy["Name"])
            break
        elif playerChoice == "r":
            print("You ran away back to the Jail Cell")
            jailCell2()
            break
        else:
            print("Error")


    # Enemy attack randomiser, will generate a random choice of enemy which will have a random level and amount of health
    while enemyHealth > 0 and playerCharacterHealth > 0:

        while True:
            print("Press 1 for", playerCharacter["Name"], "to attack with",
                  playerCharacter["Attack"][0], "or 2 to attack with",
                  playerCharacter["Attack"][2])

            attackChoice = int(input())
            # Modify here
            if attackChoice == 1:
                playerAttack = playerCharacter["Attack"][1]
                print(f"attackChoice == 1: {playerCharacter['Attack'][1]}")

                print(playerCharacter["Name"], "attack with", playerCharacter["Attack"][0],
                      "for", playerAttack, "damage")
                enemyHealth -= playerAttack
                print("enemy health", enemyHealth)
            elif attackChoice == 2:
                playerAttack = playerCharacter["Attack"][3]
                print(f"attackChoice == 2: {playerCharacter['Attack'][3]}")
                print(playerCharacter["Name"], "attack with", playerCharacter["Attack"][2],
                      "for", playerAttack, "damage")
                enemyHealth -= playerAttack
                print("enemy health", enemyHealth)
            else:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter 1 or 2.")
                continue

            if enemyHealth <= 0 or playerCharacterHealth <= 0:
                break

            enemyBattleRandomiser = random.choice([0, 2])
            print(enemy["Name"], "attacks you with", enemy["Attack"][enemyBattleRandomiser],
                  "for", enemy["Attack"][enemyBattleRandomiser + 1], "damage")
            playerCharacterHealth -= enemy["Attack"][enemyBattleRandomiser + 1]
            print(playerCharacter["Name"], "have", playerCharacterHealth, "health")

            if playerCharacterHealth <= 0:
                break

    if playerCharacterHealth > 0:
        print("YOU WIN!")
        if area == 1:
            jailCell()
        elif area == 2:
            darkPassage()
        elif area == 3:
            tortureRoom()
        elif area == 4:
            wineCeller()
        elif area == 5:
            print("You defeated the infamous Toeliath! YOU'VE WON THE GAME!!")
            play_again()
    else:
        print("Game Over!")
        play_again()


# Function to restart game if user looses
def play_again():
    while True:
        choice = input("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ").lower()
        if choice == "y":
            main_menu()
            break
        elif choice == "n":
            exit(2)
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please enter Y or N.")


def jailCell():
    global area
    global money
    global player
    area = 1
    print("Jail Cell:")
    print("")
    print("You wake up in a jail cell, it's cold, dark, and very eerie. You better watch out for enemies!")
    print("")
    print("""You walk out of your cell and to your left you see a sign, the sign says Store & Casino.
        But to your right you see a dark passage.""")
    print("")
    print(
        """You've got an option: type L to walk left and go to the Store & Casino or type R to go right, into a strange passage.""")

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "L":
            money, player = store_and_flip_coin(money, player)  # Pass money as an argument
            break
        elif user_input == "R":
            darkPassage()
            break
        else:
            print("Input Error")


# 2nd jaiCell function so when player wants to run from enemy he can get put back to his jailcell without introduction playing
def jailCell2():
    global area
    global money
    global player
    area = 1
    print("Jail Cell:")
    print("")
    print(
        """You've got an option: type L to walk left and go to the Store & Casino or type R to go right, into a strange passage.""")

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "L":
            money, player = store_and_flip_coin(money, player)  # Pass money as an argument
            break
        elif user_input == "R":
            darkPassage()
            break
        else:
            print("Input Error, please type L or R")


def darkPassage():
    global area
    area = 2
    print("The dark passage!")
    print("")
    print("You slowly creep down the hallway, searching for any potential enemies, you better watch out!")
    print("")
    print("Press S to go south, back to your jail cell")
    print("Or press N to to onwards...")
    battleChance = random.randint(1, 3)
    if battleChance == 1:
        battlesystem()
    else:
        print()

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "S":
            jailCell2()
        elif user_input == "N":
            tortureRoom()
        else:
            print("Input error")


def tortureRoom():
    global area
    area = 3
    print("The Torture Room!")
    print("You've entered a dark and terrifying torture room. Be careful and watch out for traps and enemies.")
    print("Press S to go south, back to the dark passage")
    print("Or press N to continue exploring...")
    battleChance = random.randint(1, 3)
    if battleChance == 1:
        battlesystem()
    else:
        print()

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "S":
            darkPassage()
        elif user_input == "N":
            wineCeller()

        else:
            print("Input error")


def wineCeller():
    global area
    area = 4
    print("The Wine Celler Room!")
    print("You've entered a dank cold wine celler with for some reason all the wine being missing?!.")
    print("You spot a hidden trap door")
    print("Press S to go south, back to the torture room")
    print("Or press T to investigate the trap door...")
    battleChance = random.randint(1, 3)
    if battleChance == 1:
        battlesystem()
    else:
        print()

    while True:
        user_input = input("").upper()

        if user_input == "S":
            tortureRoom()
        elif user_input == "N":
            print("You continue exploring the torture room...")
        elif user_input == "T":
            trapdoorBoss()
            battlesystem(enemy_type="toeliath")  # Pass "toeliath" as an enemy_type parameter to spawn Toeliath
        else:
            print("Input error")


def trapdoorBoss():
    global area
    area = 5
    print("You enter the trap door!")
    print("Torches light up in flames around you like a circle!")
    print("You get an uneasy feeling...")
    print("BOOM!")
    print("THE GIANT BOSS TOELIATH HAS APPEARD")
    print("You have no other choice but to fight!")
    battleChance = random.randint(0, 1)
    if battleChance == 1:
        battlesystem(boss_battle=True)
        toeliath_boss

    else:
        print()


def store_and_flip_coin(money, player):
    while True:
        print("Welcome to the casino/shop!")
        choice = input("Do you want to gamble (g), shop (s), or go back to the jail cell (b)?: ").lower()
        if choice == "g":
            money = gamble(money)
        elif choice == "s":
            money, player = store(money, player)
        elif choice == "b":
            jailCell()
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")


# starting amount of money
money = 200000


# coinflip script
def flip_coin():
    return random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])


def gamble(money):
    while True:
        print("You have", money, "dollars")
        bet = take_bet(money)
        coin = flip_coin()
        print("The coin landed on", coin, "")
        if coin == 'heads':
            money += bet
            print("You won", bet, "dollars!")
        else:
            money -= bet
            print("You lost", bet, "dollars")
        if money <= 0:
            print("Game over, you ran out of money")
            break
        play_again = input("Play again? (Y/N): ")
        if play_again.lower() == "n":
            break
    return money


def store(money, player, ):
    global toeliath_boss

    print("Welcome to the store where you can buy upgraded weapons and armor.")
    store_items = [{"Name": "God Sword",
                    "Attack": 14,
                    "Cost": 75},
                   {"Name": "Mystical wand of light",
                    "Attack": 16,
                    "Cost": 100, },
                   {"Name": "Admin Power",
                    "Attack": 6666,
                    "Cost": 6666},
                   {"Name": "Slingshot",
                    "Attack": 1000, "Cost": 250}]

    # display store items
    print("Available items:")
    for item in store_items:
        item_details = f"{item['Name']} - Cost: {item['Cost']}"
        if 'Attack' in item:
            item_details += f", Attack: {item['Attack']}"
        print(item_details)

    # allow player to buy items
    while True:
        item_name = input("Enter the name of the item you want to buy (or press enter to exit): ")
        if not item_name:
            break
        for item in store_items:
            if item['Name'] == item_name:
                if item['Cost'] > money:
                    print("Not enough money")
                else:
                    money -= item['Cost']
                    print(f"You bought {item_name} for {item['Cost']} dollars")

                    # Update player's attack damage when item is purchased in store
                    # Only keep attack of last item
                    if 'Attack' in item:
                        player[4] = ["New Attack 1", item['Attack'], "New Attack 2", item['Attack']] # Modify here
                        print(f"player: {player}")

                    if item_name == "Slingshot":
                        toeliath_boss["is_defeatable"] = True

                    break
        else:
            print("Item not found")

    print(f"Money left after store: {money}")
    return money, player


def take_bet(money):
    while True:
        try:
            bet = int(input("Enter your bet: "))
            if bet <= money:
                return bet
            else:
                print("You don't have enough money to make that bet.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")


# main menue to give user greeting and instructions on how to play
def main_menu():
    global money
    while True:
        print("Welcome to Dungeons Of Dark!")
        print("This is a simple text-based turn game where you've been locked in a dungeon.")
        print("Follow along with what the game tells you, and you'll be fine.")
        print("Make sure to earn money by betting on a coin flip and use that money to buy yourself upgraded weapons.")
        print("To win make sure you have the Slingshot!")
        print("Good luck and have fun!")
        user_input = input("Press Enter to start the game...")
        if user_input == "":
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please try again..")

    jailCell()


# Call the main_menu function to start the game
main_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using local (instead of global) variable `player` (defined in line 55) in rest of the function `battlesystem`, so program is using those items:

```py
["Pheonix punches", random.randint(5, 11), "poisonous intimidation", random.randint(4, 9)]
```

instead of those bought in shop

btw. I strongly recommend you to reorganise a little bit your code - the more messy it is the harder it's to analyse where the bug is, by that I mean stop using global variables and use objects or dictionaries instead of magic lists and numbers